# Getting data from clipboard

Tags: c++, debugging, winapi, codeblocks

I am trying to get data from clipboard but it doesn't seem to be displaying any data when i copy to my clipboard
Here is my clipboard class

```
namespace Diall_ClipBoard_catch
{
   class ClipBoard
   {
       private:
           ::HANDLE dHDat;
           ::std::string tmpstringsign;
           bool isopen;
           char * dHbuffer;
           char * dHbuffertemp;
           char * dNtoken;
   public:
        ClipBoard(void)
        {
           this->dHbuffer = "";
           this->dHbuffertemp = "";
           this->tmpstringsign = "dnb_4554_2102";
           this->isopen = false;
        };
        ~ClipBoard(void)
        {
            if(this-isopen)
            {
                ::CloseClipboard();
                this->isopen = false;
            }

        }
        void GetData(void)
        {
            this->Start();
            if(this->isopen)
            {
                this->dHDat = ::GetClipboardData(CF_TEXT);

                if(this->dHDat)
                {
                    this->dHbuffer = (char*)::GlobalLock(this->dHDat);

                    if(::std::strcmp(this->dHbuffertemp, this->dHbuffer)!=0 && this->dHbuffer != "" && this->dHbuffer != NULL)
                    {
                        this->dHbuffertemp = this->dHbuffer;
                        ::std::cout << this->dHbuffer << "\n";
                    }

                    ::GlobalUnlock(this->dHDat);
                }
                this->~ClipBoard();
                ::Sleep(1000);
            }
        }
   private:
        Start(void)
        {

        }
   } ;
}
```

And here is my main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <cstring>
#include "Clipboard.h"


int main()
{
    ::Diall_ClipBoard_catch::ClipBoard * clipboard = new Diall_ClipBoard_catch::ClipBoard();
    while(1)
    {
        clipboard->GetData();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Even though I do not get any error when i build and run on Codeblocks, I still don't get any data displayed to my console.
Even though I have played around with the compiler settings on codeblock, I still haven't been able to get it to work

Comment: Are you sure the clipboard contains CF_TEXT data? Also, where is the OpenClipboard function?

Comment: As Michael says, you don't seem to have opened the clipboard. If you did any error checking you'd know this.

Comment: Also, DO NOT call `this->~ClipBoard();` in `GetData()` at all. `Start()` needs to call `OpenClipboard()`, and then add another function for `GetData()` to call `CloseClipboard()` when done. Also, rather than polling the clipboard for changes, use `SetClipboardViewer()` or `AddClipboardFormatListener()` to be notified when the clipboard changes. Or, at least use `GetClipboardSequenceNumber()` in your polling loop before calling `GetData()`. See [Monitoring Clipboard Contents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/using-the-clipboard#monitoring-clipboard-contents)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments have given enough information to fix this problem.

In the `Start()` function, you need some API calls, such as [OpenClipboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-openclipboard), [SetClipboardData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setclipboarddata).

And you did not set `isopen` to true, so when debugging, you will find that the breakpoint cannot reach `GetClipboardData ()`.

Add the following code to test:

```
Start(void)
{
     const char* output = "Hello World";
     const size_t len = strlen(output) + 1;
     HGLOBAL hMem = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE, len);
     memcpy(GlobalLock(hMem), output, len);
     GlobalUnlock(hMem);
     if (!OpenClipboard(NULL))
     {
         return;
     }
     EmptyClipboard();
     SetClipboardData(CF_TEXT, hMem);
     this->isopen = TRUE;
}
```

Note: The above code uses `SetClipboardData` to copy the text to the clipboard, and then uses `GetClipboardData` to get the text.

You can also use the clipboard to copy text yourself. Run the code and check whether the return value of the [GetClipboardSequenceNumber](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getclipboardsequencenumber) function has changed. If it changes, it means that the clipboard contents have changed or the clipboard has been emptied.

Code Sample:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <cstring>

namespace Diall_ClipBoard_catch
{
    class ClipBoard
    {
    private:
        ::HANDLE dHDat;
        ::std::string tmpstringsign;
        bool isopen;
        char* dHbuffer;
        char* dHbuffertemp;
        char* dNtoken;
    public:
        ClipBoard(void)
        {
            this->dHbuffer = const_cast <char*>("");
            this->dHbuffertemp = const_cast <char*>("");
            this->tmpstringsign = "dnb_4554_2102";
            this->isopen = false;
        };
        ~ClipBoard(void)
        {         

        }
        void GetData(void)
        {
            this->Start();
            if (this->isopen)
            {
                this->dHDat = ::GetClipboardData(CF_TEXT);

                if (this->dHDat)
                {
                    this->dHbuffer = (char*)::GlobalLock(this->dHDat);

                    if (::std::strcmp(this->dHbuffertemp, this->dHbuffer) != 0 && this->dHbuffer != "" && this->dHbuffer != NULL)
                    {
                        this->dHbuffertemp = this->dHbuffer;
                        ::std::cout << this->dHbuffer << "\n";
                    }

                    ::GlobalUnlock(this->dHDat);
                }
                EmptyClipboard();
                CloseClipboard();
                this->isopen = FALSE;
                ::Sleep(1000);
            }
        }
    private:
        void Start(void)
        {
            if (!OpenClipboard(NULL))
            {
                return;
            }
            this->isopen = TRUE;
        }
    };
}

int main()
{
    ::Diall_ClipBoard_catch::ClipBoard* clipboard = new Diall_ClipBoard_catch::ClipBoard();   
    int temp1 = 0, temp2 = 0;
    EmptyClipboard();
    while (1)
    {      
        temp1 = GetClipboardSequenceNumber();
        if (temp1!= temp2)
        {
            clipboard->GetData();
        }

        temp2 = temp1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Debug:

[image: 1]

Comment: This was very helpful. I can see clearly where I made the mistake. Thanks everyone for the help.

Comment: @KingKesh Glad to hear that!